# Password Protected Zip: if attacker had one file, can use it to decrypt all files?

Tags: passwords, brute-force, file-encryption, password-cracking

Consider a folder containing the following files:

(file1.txt, file2.doc, file3.pdf) all zipped and password protected, **if attacker had one of these file, can use it for decrypting all without knowing the password?**

Note: I used very strong password which is 100 in length for example:

> nZqQb=r07W.G'sZaHf$>&cC]3'9={1U1lPtxT514h&$$V1g05i.ZbIiX65>ckF65G64Tx6NrKR3688R81G6u4D~:J7pr616dOK*9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be a form of know plain-text attack. Zip uses AES these days to encrypt files and AES is not susceptible to these type of attacks.

Please refer to: [Compute the AES-encryption key given the plaintext and its ciphertext?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/compute-the-aes-encryption-key-given-the-plaintext-and-its-ciphertext)

Comment: I also found that [here](http://www.elcomsoft.com/archpr.html): `If you have a file from the encrypted ZIP archive in your hands, the whole archive can be usually unlocked in minutes by applying the known-plaintext attack. Similar ARJ archives are unlocked instantly. Fast recovery available only in case of "classical" encryption, not AES.`

Answer (score 1):

In don't believe that that would work on modern versions of zip software (as @lucasKauffman says), however there is a known plaintext attack for older version of zip crypto (more details [here](http://www.elcomsoft.co.uk/help/archpr/index.html?known_plaintext_attack_%28zip%29.html) ), so if the archive uses that then it would enable the other files to be extracted potentially.